# Loading data on UITableView up scroll

Tags: ios, uitableview

I would like to show activityindicator and load more content from server when scroll goes out of UITableView.

I saw it in several News Feed applications:

[image: http://i40.tinypic.com/sf9c0o.png]

Does anyone know this, please help me, thanks!

Comment: It's called `UIRefreshControl`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a `UIRefreshControl`

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.title = @"News Feed";
    self.allNewsEntries = [NSMutableArray array];
    [self downloadNewsEntries];

    UIRefreshControl *refreshControl = [[UIRefreshControl alloc] init];
    [refreshControl addTarget:self action:@selector(refreshContent)
             forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
    self.refreshControl = refreshControl;
}

-(void) refreshContent {
    [self.allNewsEntries removeAllObjects];
    [self downloadNewsEntries];
    [self.refreshControl endRefreshing];
}
```